# Getting email of Facebook friend using Facebook User Id (java script)

Tags: javascript, facebook, email

Need a bit of help getting the email address of Facebook friend using his Facebook User Id.
This is the code I have:

```
//this is the getLoginStatus - with email permissions
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  // Check login status on load, and if the user is
  // already logged in, go directly to the welcome message.
  if (response.status == 'connected') {
    onLogin(response);
  } else {
    // Otherwise, show Login dialog first.
    FB.login(function(response) {
      onLogin(response);
    }, {scope: 'user_friends, public_profile, email'});
  }
});

//this the code I use to try to fetch the email address
    var email="";
    FB.api(
    "/" + userIds[0],
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        email = response.email;
      }
    }
);
```

Please note that I get a response (with first_name, id, gender etc) but the email is not included - even though my app requested email access permissions and all if my facebook users using my app.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: A user do not have to accept the `email` permission even if its asked for. Each permission is possible to decline but still use the app, if you don't handle it yourself.

Comment: in this case, I use test users (to validate all users accept the email permission) - I still do not get the email...

Comment: Does the test user have an email? Is the API path not supposed to be `/me` and not `/userId`?

Comment: You can only read the email address for the current user of your app, not for their friends. It doesn’t matter that the friend has given your app permission to read their email – you can only read it using their own user access token.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be the correct answer...